# When to calc std dev? Before or after?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a sample which is analysed 5 times. I get an average of these 5 results.
I repeat this test in triplicate to give me three answers which I then find an average of.
My question: should I use the standard deviation of all 15, or just the standard deviation of the final 3 results?
Thanks

Comment: Insightful question.

Comment: Use *for what purpose?*  What do you want this SD to represent or measure?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the standard deviation of
each of the three runs of five. Then "pool"
the three variances. There is some chance
that the three runs will differ slightly, so
this pooled result may differ somewhat
from the standard deviation of all 15 observations. I would use the pooled SD, rather than the standard deviation of all 15 observations.

[The idea of the pooled variance is similar to the
pooled variance in a pooled 2-sample t test (but
generalized to three groups). It is also the
same idea as computing the mean square for residuals in a one-factor ANOVA with three levels of the factor. See end note.]

Computations, using R mainly as a calculator:

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rnorm(5, 50, 7)
x2 = rnorm(5, 52, 7)
x3 = rnorm(5, 48, 7)
```

Stripchart of the three runs:

```
stripchart(list(x1,x2,x3), ylim=c(.5,3.5), pch=19)
```

[image]

```
s1 = sd(x1);  s2 = sd(x2);  s3 = sd(x3)
s1;  s2;  s3
[1] 6.503417
[1] 10.37375
[1] 4.973423

# pooling
v.p = (4*s1^2 + 4*s2^2 + 4*s3^2)/12;  v.p
[1] 58.21469
sd.p = sqrt(v.p);  sd.p
[1] 7.629855

# all 15
sd.all = sd(c(x1,x2,x3));  sd.all
[1] 7.143844
```

---

*Note:* Here is an ANOVA table for the three groups,
showing the mean square for residuals, which agrees with `v.p` (except for rounding).

```
x = c(x1, x2, x3)
g = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=5))
anova(lm(x~g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
g          2  15.91   7.953  0.1366 0.8736
Residuals 12 698.58  58.215
```

The large P-value $0.8736 > 0.05 = 5\%$
indicates that that no significant differences among the three group sample means is detected.

I suppose one purpose of your experiment may be to estimate the population standard deviation $\sigma.$ You don't have much information in your 15 observations.

However, in case you do want to use the pooled variance
$V_p  = 58.21469$ to get a 95% CI for
the population standard deviation $\sigma,$
you can use the relationship
$\frac{12V_p}{\sigma^2} \sim
\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 3(5-1)=12),$ which has
$P\left(4.404 \le \frac{12V_p}{\sigma^2} \le 23.34\right) = 0.95,$ to get
the 95% CI $(5.47,\, 12.59)$ for $\sigma.$

```
qchisq(c(.025,.975), 12)
[1]  4.403789 23.336664
sqrt(12*v.p/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 12))
[1]  5.471262 12.594870
```

Comment: Please see my comment to the question.  In particular, where does the question ask about testing?

Comment: Nowhere, But the pooled variances used in testing seem a natural response.